# How can I get current page dom

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For example:

```
<div id="d">ss</d>
```

How can I get the div by id?

Comment: From where? A content script? A popup? A background page?

Comment: Start with valid HTML <div id="d">ss</div>

Comment: At backgournd page.How can I access current web page?

Answer (score 1):

You should access the web page using the contentWindow variable when writing a Chrome Extension.

```
contentWindow.document.getElementById("d");
```

Comment: background.html
"
<html>
<head>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab){
        alert(contentWindow.getElementById('gc-topnav'));
    } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
"

how can I access the web page using the contentWindow variable?
TKs~

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement:

```
document.getElementById('d');
```

Comment: not success.
the code "document.getElementById('id');" in in background.html. so can not get the div.
I want click the extensison button that can do somethine with current page

Comment: You mean document.getElementById('d'); ?